# Theorem 7.13 Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis. Regularity of measure

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, lebesgue-measure

I'm having trouble with the proof of the following:

> **Theorem 7.13** Associate to each $x \in \mathbb{R}^k$ a sequence $\left\{ E_i(x) \right\}$ that shrinks to $x$ nicely. If $\mu$ is a complex Borel measure and $\mu \perp m$, then
> $$
> \lim_{i,+\infty} \frac{\mu(E_i(x))}{m(E_i(x))} = 0 \;\;\; a.e. [x] \;\;\; (1)
> $$

> **Proof**: The Jordan decomposition theorem shows that it suffices to prove under the additional assumptions that $\mu \geq 0$. In that case, arguing as in the proof of theorem 7.10
> $$
> \frac{\alpha(x)\mu(E_i(x))}{m(E_i(x))} \leq \frac{\mu(E_i(x))}{m(B(x,r_i))} \leq \frac{\mu(B(x,r_i))}{m(B(x,r_i))}
> $$
> Hence (1) is a consequence of the special case
> $$
> (D\mu)(x) = 0 \;\;\; a.e. \;\;\; [m],
> $$
> which will now be proved.
> The upper derivative $\overline{D}\mu$, defined by
> $$
> (\overline{D}\mu)(x) = \lim_{i \to \infty} \left[ \sup_{0 < r < 1/n} (Q_r\mu)(x) \right] \;\;\; (x \in \mathbb{R}^k)
> $$
> is a Borel function, because the quantity in brackets decreases as $n$ increases and is, for each $n$, a lower semicontinuous function of $x$; the reasoning used in Sec. 7.2 proves this.

Here it comes the part I don't understand.

> Choose $\lambda > 0$, $\epsilon > 0$. Since $ \mu \perp m$, $\mu$ is concentrated on a set of Lebesgue measure $0$. The regularity of $\mu$ (Theorem 2.18) shows therefore that there is a compact set $K$, with $m(K) = 0$, $\mu(K) > \left\lVert \mu \right\rVert - \epsilon$.

1. I don't understand where the existance of $K$ comes from (is maybe given by the property of the measure in theorem 2.18? Or some construction maybe used in the proof of such theorem?).
2. Where do $m(K) = 0$ and $\mu(K) > \left\lVert \mu \right\rVert - \epsilon$ come from?

Probably my two questions are actually connected, but I can't really figure.

Comment: I think the tag proof-explanation helps readers know the type of question.  But only five tags are allowed in one question.  I removed Lebesgue integral.  Please feel free to edit the tags if you want to keep it.

Comment: Yes, sorry I usually put the proof-explanation tag. Thank you.

Comment: I am not saying you need to do this but inserting the statement of Theorem 2.18 in your question would be really helpful...

Answer (score 2):

We are assuming that $\mu $ is  a positive measure. There exists $A$ such that $m(A)=0$ and $\mu (A^{c})=0$. By regularity there exists  compact set $K \subseteq A$ such that $\mu (K) >\mu (A)-\epsilon$. Note that $\|\mu\|=\mu (A)+\mu (A^{c})=\mu (A)$.  Hence $\mu (K) >\|\mu\| -\epsilon$. Of course $m(K) \leq m(A)=0$.

Comment: Why is there an $A$ such that $m(A) =\mu(A^c) = 0$? Why is $\mu(K) > \mu(A) - \epsilon$? Is it literally the definition of regularity? (Inner regularity).

Comment: @user8469759 Definition of $\mu$ being singular w.r.t. $m$ and definitioin of regularity of $\mu$.