# Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis - Application of theorem 2.18 of to 7.13 in order to prove regularity of measure

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation

Follow up question to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3926782/theorem-7-13-rudins-real-and-complex-analysis-regularity-of-measure).

In order to show that $\mu$ is regular apparently the author uses the following theorem

> **Theorem 2.18** Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space in which every open set is $\sigma$-compact. Let $\lambda$ any positive Borel measure on $X$ such that $\lambda(K) < \infty$ for every compact set $K$. The $\lambda$ is regular.

I understand that the locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ is $\mathbb{R}^k$ in theorem 7.13, $\mu$ is positive by hypothesis. The bit I'm missing is $\mu(K) < \infty$?

There's a remark in the definition 2.16 which I think might help,

> For example, in the situation described in Theorem 2.14, every $\sigma$-compact set has $\sigma$-finite measure.

So the answer might be in the Riesz representation theorem 2.14, point (b) specifically

> we have
> $
> \mu(K) < \infty
> $ for every compact set $K \subset X$

Is this the reason why $\mu$ in theorem 7.13 is regular?

Comment: Maybe you should read the book more carefully. $\mu$ is a complex Borel measure, and **complex** measures cannot take infinite values.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor Theorem 7.13 says *it suffices to show this for $\mu \geq 0$*. The author doesn't prove the complex case but only the positive one, the complex case can be argued using the Jordan decomposition. Unless I am missing something I don't think your observation is correct. Pretty sure also the notation $\mu(K) < \infty$ also refers to real valued measure (positive).

Comment: See Section $6.1$, where they talk about convergence of the series in $(1)$ as part of the requirement.